# The same Facebook comments appear on every post on Blogger

Tags: facebook, comments, blogs, blogger

I have a blog on Blogger and I just installed the new FaceBook Comments plugin. The code looks like this.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d){
var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));</script>
<fb:comments href="zephraz.blogspot.com" num_posts="10" width="490" colorscheme="dark"></fb:comments>
```

I am really having a difficult time because the same comments appear on each of the post on my blog. I am a newbie and I know nothing about coding and etc. Can anyone help me on this one?

Comment: Don't put your titles in [ALL CAPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability). It's like shouting, and it's less readable.

Answer (score 5):

Change:

```
href="zephraz.blogspot.com"
```

To:

```
expr:href='data:post.url'
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding facebook comments to blogspot is pain. But not impossible at all.

I had used same code which you are using now and my comments were same for entire blog.

I didnt want this. It gives you different comments for different posts.

refer [Adding Facebook Comments for Blogger](http://mayura4ever.blogspot.com/2011/06/add-facebook-comment-social-plugin-to.html)

Follow the instruction properly and you will get the result.
It works. I have tried this on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I had the same question. Through research, I stumbled upon the below forum thread and followed the [steps](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=227562).

So far, I have no problems with the comments plugin on this blog I'm hired to work on.
check the plugin working [here](http://hotgirlsofasia.blogspot.com/).

It wont be on the homepage, just click any post, it will have the comments box below.

Answer (score 1):

Adding:
`expr:title='data:post.title'` 
`expr:href='data:post.canonicalUrl'` 
`expr:xid='data:post.id'`

instead of the blog url (in addition to the main code that has to be added in the head section of the page) adds the comment form to individual posts instead of the form appearing for all the posts.

Even I had the same problem and finally found the solution for it. Works fine.

GBU
Arti

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? 
 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : 
 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php echo $url; ?>" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
```