# What's the deal with "data: post.url", "data: post.title", etc

Tags: html, blogger

Would someone be so kind as to explain what this data object is (if it is an object) and if there is any documentation on it.

I was adding social sharing buttons to an app and decided I wanted to put a share to Blogger button on there, just for the fun of it. I could not find a page that had an official 'share to Blogger' button, like Facebook has an official 'like' button, or Twitter, a 'tweet' button. What I did find was this [post on adding sharing buttons to a blog](http://sedatkurtulus.blogspot.ca/2010/01/simple-share-buttons-for-blogger.html) with the attached text file. I noticed that most, if not all of the HTML `<a>` tags use the 'data: post.url' and 'data: post.title' to dynamically grab the URL and title of the blog post.

Example:

```
<a expr:href='&quot;http://reddit.com/submit?url=&quot; + data:post.url + &quot;&amp;title=&quot; + data:post.title' target='_blank' title='Share On Reddit !'><img alt='Share On Reddit !' src='http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_YUvD9j84Cik/TBvM2-Sw3ZI/AAAAAAAAAHk/QKghefISkNc/reddit.gif' style='width:16px; height:16px; padding:0; border:0; vertical-align:middle;'/></a> 

<a expr:href='&quot;http://www.blogger.com/blog_this.pyra?t&quot; + &quot;&amp;u=&quot; + data:post.url + &quot;&amp;n=&quot; + data:post.title + &quot;&amp;pli=&quot; + 1' target='_blank' title='Post To Blogger !'><img alt='Post To Blogger !' src='http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_YUvD9j84Cik/TBvMqnnrVtI/AAAAAAAAAG8/O65EnRFSHFk/blogger.gif' style='width:16px; height:16px; padding:0; border:0; vertical-align:middle;'/></a> 

<a expr:href='&quot;http://www.friendfeed.com/share?link=&quot; + data:post.url + &quot;&amp;title=&quot; + data:post.title' target='_blank' title='Share On Friend Feed !'><img alt='Share On Friend Feed !' src='http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_YUvD9j84Cik/TBvMxcy7H8I/AAAAAAAAAHU/UfNllYiyznA/friendfeed.gif' style='width:16px; height:16px; padding:0; border:0; vertical-align:middle;'/></a>
```

When looking into this on Stack Overflow, I've found that it is suggested for people using [social comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403310/the-same-facebook-comments-appear-on-every-post-on-blogger/8581433#8581433) and [share buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714662/share-buttons-share-homepage-instead-of-actual-page/17623313#17623313) who are having issues with sharing their URLs, though, it is notable that none of the answers have been marked correct.

Is this something that is strictly limited to the Blogger/Blogspot platforms, or is it something that is handled by the browser? I haven't been able to find anything in the DOM referring to data or post. I'd be interested to know how this can be used more broadly and if it should be used at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, `data:` is a namespace that scopes the data available from Blogger that can be included in a template.  The authoritative list of what's availabe [is here](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/47270?hl=en).

It is Blogger-centric.

The other namespaces are `b:` which deals with layout and control flow, and `expr:` which keys the engine into the fact that the tags involve data from Blogger (as you have above).

A good tutorial [is here](http://thoughtsomething.blogspot.com/2009/01/understanding-blogger-template-1.html).

Comment: Well how about that. Thanks John. I was thinking POST like the http request method, not the post of a blog--but it's kind of obvious in retrospect.

Answer (score 2):

In the Blogger template  `data:post.url` returns the url of the current page,`data:post.title` returns the title of the post.These are terminologies are specific to the blogger API and hence these code would work in blogger template and nowhere else.

For example,
typing                     `<a expr:href='data:post.url'>` in the blogger template,would give the output of `<a href="http://urlofthepage">`

So if I go to `http://meow.blogspot.com/2011/03/ab.html` the code which will appear in the source code will be  `<a href="http://meow.blogspot.com/2011/03/ab.html">`