# Blogger code data:post.url used as clickable link with an image button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My website is logjik.com. I have two social buttons in posts and they show also in my main page and i used this solution because even though i'm in home page i can share my post link (similar to 9gag is my home page):

```
.shr-btn-scl .twitterbtn{background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/waBaJl0.png); display:block; background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:42px;  
    width:185px;}
.shr-btn-scl .facebookbtn{background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/XNIyP7z.png);display:block;
    height:42px;

    width:185px; background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

---

```
<div class='shr-btn-scl'>

<div class='btncontainer'>
<ul class='share-story'>                         
                            <li><a class='facebookbtn' data-title='Facebook' expr:href='&quot;http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=&quot; + data:post.url + &quot;&amp;title=&quot;+ data:post.title' onclick='window.open(this.href, &apos;windowName&apos;, &apos;width=550, height=600, left=24, top=24, scrollbars, resizable&apos;); return false;' rel='nofollow'/>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                              <a class='twitterbtn' data-title='Twitter' expr:href='&quot;http://twitter.com/share?url=&quot; + data:post.url + &quot;&amp;title=&quot; + data:post.title' onclick='window.open(this.href, &apos;windowName&apos;, &apos;width=550, height=600, left=24, top=24, scrollbars, resizable&apos;); return false;' rel='nofollow'/>
  </li>                                                  
  </ul>
  </div>
    </div>
```

---

AND i would like to add a third button just with a clickable image sending me from home page to the post on click. Is there a way to use data:post.url as a link with a clickable image? How can i make this code work:

```
`<a href="data:post.url" title=""><img border="0" src="http://i.imgur.com/ivHxNCj.jpg"/></a>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256453/whats-the-deal-with-datapost-url-datapost-title-etc) which might help you.

I assumed you were talking about Blogger templates. If so, this should work:

```
<a expr:href="data:post.url" title=""><img border="0" src="http://i.imgur.com/ivHxNCj.jpg"/></a>
```