# hide url javascript is not updating after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been reading every post I can find but coming up short. I understand that attempting to mask the url is not best practice but this is for a personal project. The goal is to visit a page that appears to have no clickable links. The page has animation that reveals a login form.

javascript that performs the animation, 1st click reveals the login form, clicking any of the images will close the form and hide it.

```
function login() {
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.loginlink').removeAttr('href');
    $('#ai1, #ai3, #ai4, #ai5').attr('href', 'javascript:logout();');
    $('#i1').animate({left: '-=110'});
    $('#i4').animate({top: '-=110'});
    $('#i5').animate({top: '+=110'});
    $('#di2').animate({opacity: 0});
    $('#i3').animate({left: '+=110'}, function() {
        $('#i2').replaceWith('<form id="f"><input class="a" value="Username" id="name" name="user" type="text" /><br /><div class="fs"><br /></div><input class="a" value="Password" id="pass" name="pass" type="password" /><br /><div class="fs"><br /></div><div style="position: relative; left: -25px; display: inline;"><input type="checkbox" name="remember" /> Remember me?</div><input style="position: relative; left: 25px;" type="submit" value=" Login " /></form>');
        $('#di2').animate({opacity: 1});
        $('#i1').css('z-index', '10');
    });
    $('.login').addClass('logout');
    $('.login').removeClass('login');
    $('#t1').animate({opacity: 0});
    $('#t2').animate({opacity: 0});
});
}
function logout() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.loginlink').removeAttr('href');
            $('#di2').animate({opacity: 0}, function() {
                $('#f').replaceWith('<img id="i2" src="/static/common/w.png" />');
    $('#di2').animate({opacity: 1}, function() {
                $('#i1').animate({left: '+=110'});
            $('#i4').animate({top: '+=110'});
                    $('#i5').animate({top: '-=110'});
                    $('#i3').animate({left: '-=110'}, function() {
            $('#t1').animate({opacity: 1});
                $('#t2').animate({opacity: 1});
        $('#ai1, #ai2, #ai3, #ai4, #ai5').attr('href', 'javascript:login();');
        });
        });
    });
            $('.logout').addClass('login');
    $('.logout').removeClass('logout');
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#name').live("focus", function() {
    if($('#name').val() === "Username") $('#name').val("");
});
$('#name').live("blur", function() {
    if($('#name').val() === "") $('#name').val("Username");
});
    $('#pass').live("focus", function() {
            if($('#pass').val() === "Password") $('#pass').val("");
    });
    $('#pass').live("blur", function() {
            if($('#pass').val() === "") $('#pass').val("Password");
    });
});
```

javascript that I found here to mask the url: [hide url at status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27716122/hide-url-at-status-bar)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("a.loginlink").each(function (index, element){
            var href = $(this).attr("href");
            $(this).attr("hiddenhref", href);
            $(this).removeAttr("href");
        });
        $("a.loginlink").click(function(){
            url = $(this).attr("hiddenhref");
            window.open(url, '_self');
        })
    });
</script>
```

and lastly the html:

```
<table id="derp">
            <td id="a"></td>
            <td id="b">
                    <span class="login">
                            <a id="ai4" class="loginlink" href="javascript:login();"><img id="i4" src="/static/common/top.png" /></a>
                            <a id="ai1" class="loginlink" href="javascript:login();"><img id="i1" src="/static/common/left.png" /></a>
                            <a id="ai3" class="loginlink" href="javascript:login();"><img id="i3" src="/static/common/right.png" /></a>
                            <a id="ai5" class="loginlink" href="javascript:login();"><img id="i5" src="/static/common/bottom.png" /></a>
                            <div id="di2"><a id="ai2" class="loginlink" href="javascript:login();"><img id="i2" src="/static/common/w.png" /></a></div>
                    </span><br /><br />
            </td>
            <td id="c"></td>
</table>
```

It was suggested that the html I used is horrible. But I have 0 experience and all work is by hacking away at what I can find.

The issue I can't currently resolve is hiding the form after opening.

Steps to reproduce:
1. Load page
2. Click the region(no status bar as link is masked), no status bar as the link is replaced with hiddenhref="javascript:login();"
3. Login form appears
4. Images should then take on the link javascript:logout() and be hidden on hover but this does not happen. Instead the link retains javascript:login(); and clicking again makes the images animate with open instead of close

Comment: That code is meant to open a new window with the URL hidden, and it's probably being blocked by a popup blocker anyway.

Comment: @cuniculus pop-up blockers generally allow new windows to be popped if there is a user-initiated event in the stack. Here, it the call to `login()` were moved from `href` to an `onclick` attribute the pop-up blocker would allow it.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
window.onload=function(){
  var as=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
 for(key in as){
  (function(a){
    var url=a.href;
     a.href="javascript:void(0)";
    a.onclick=function(){
      if(url.split("javascript:")[0]){
        eval(url.split("javascript:")[0]);
      }else{
        location.href=url;
      }
   };
   })(as[key]);
  }
  };
```

That supports resolving javascript urls. However it would be better to just use onclick eventhandlers, that call the functions directly. You could implement it in the upper code like this:

```
 if(url=="javascript:login()"){
  login.call(this);//you could also do login(), depends on wether you wanna use this...
 }else{
   //open url
 }
```