# Hide url link on hover

Tags: url, download

I've a code to save image but i need to hide url on hover. 
i tried that one solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27716122/hide-url-at-status-bar/27716498#27716498) . but it redirect me to image url. here is my code:

```
<?php echo '<a href="' . $imgsrc_full[0] . '" download="image.jpg"> Download </a>'; ?>
```

Comment: Why? That information is helpful to users.

Comment: This sounds like an [X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)